# Using pointer in boolean expression of if statement

Tags: c, pointers

I am getting input as `argv`, `argc` and I want to return TRUE of FALSE according to the input. My code is :

```
int is_valid_regexp(const char* regexp);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
  if (!is_valid_regexp(argv[1])){
    fprintf(stderr, "wrong regular expression format:%s", argv[1]);
    return(EXIT_FAILURE):
  }
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int is_valid_regexp(const char* regexp)
{
  do{
    if(*regexp == '\\')
      return FALSE;
  }while (regexp++ != '\0');
  return TRUE;
}
```

The program executes and then stops working. I think something is wrong with `if(*regexp == '\\') return FALSE` - the program works well if I exclude that part. Does it have something to do with pointer problem?

Comment: `}while (*regexp++ != '\0');`

Comment: Oh, I've mistaken! thanks.....

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Can you make your comment an answer, seeing as it solved the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 }while (regexp++ != '\0');
```

Here, `regexp` is a POINTER, which is equal to address of area of memory. `regexp++` just shift right on one position this pointer. As type of pointer is size_t (unsigned __int32) you go outside your string.
Use

```
`}while (*regexp++ != '\0');`
```

to solve your problem.